# how to fix: /bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: gcc, makefile, gfortran

I am trying to compile a Fortran code (package) with gfortran in a Linux server, on which I have no root access.
It has a Makefile and when I run `make` I get this error

```
/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but gcc is already installed on cluster.

```
gcc -v

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC)
```

or libgfortran:

```
locate libgfortran

/usr/lib/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libgfortran.spec
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libgfortranbegin.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libgfortran.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libgfortranbegin.a
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.1
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
/usr/share/doc/gcc-gfortran-4.8.5/ChangeLog-2002.libgfortran.bz2
/usr/share/doc/gcc-gfortran-4.8.5/ChangeLog-2003.libgfortran.bz2
/usr/share/doc/gcc-gfortran-4.8.5/ChangeLog-2004.libgfortran.bz2
/usr/share/doc/gcc-gfortran-4.8.5/ChangeLog-2005.libgfortran.bz2
/usr/share/doc/gcc-gfortran-4.8.5/ChangeLog-2006.libgfortran.bz2
/usr/share/doc/gcc-gfortran-4.8.5/ChangeLog-2007.libgfortran.bz2
/usr/share/doc/gcc-gfortran-4.8.5/ChangeLog-2008.libgfortran.bz2
/usr/share/doc/gcc-gfortran-4.8.5/ChangeLog-2009.libgfortran.bz2
/usr/share/doc/gcc-gfortran-4.8.5/ChangeLog-2010.libgfortran.bz2
/usr/share/doc/gcc-gfortran-4.8.5/ChangeLog-2011.libgfortran.bz2
/usr/share/doc/gcc-gfortran-4.8.5/ChangeLog-2012.libgfortran.bz2
/usr/share/doc/gcc-gfortran-4.8.5/ChangeLog.libgfortran.bz2
```

and this is the output of installed package

```
yum list gcc-gfortran

Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast

Installed Packages
gcc-gfortran.x86_64                                                 4.8.5-16.el7                                                 @local-rhels7.4-x86_64--install-rhels7.4-x86_64
```

The question is why it can not find libgfortran, while gcc is installed?
I have also tried to update `$PATH` but it did not change anything.
I am just a user of the server without root access.

Comment: Do you actually have the `gcc-gfortran` package installed?  That should include not just the compiler but also the development library.  It looks like you may have, but then again there's a weird version-number inconsistency among the files in your listing.

Comment: yeah you are right. actually i have also tried to install gcc 4.9.2 in my local directory but i could not then i have deleted. so its gcc 4.8.5 with a lots of libraries which is installed on the server by root. I am trying to compile a scientific code that needs gfortran to compile.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  You appear to be running RedHat EL7 or one of its clones.  If you execute the command `yum list gcc-gfortran`, does it show the package as installed or as available?

Comment: Ah sorry i got it now, yes it is the output :

Comment: Installed Packages
gcc-gfortran.x86_64                                                 4.8.5-16.el7                                                 @local-rhels7.4-x86_64--install-rhels7.4-x86_6

Comment: i have also edited it in question,

Comment: Try to modify your linking flags (`LDFLAGS` perhaps) to include `-Wl,--verbose` so that you can inspect what paths linker is considering.